# Single-choice list with input-field

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When the user hits a button in my app, it shows a persistent single-choice-list with use of `AlertDialog.Builder` and the `setSingleChoiceItems()`-method. The list is populated with values from a simple array, which is not known at compile-time. When the user hits "OK" in the dialog, the value is saved.

Now, I would like an option in this list where the value is a textbox and not populated from the array. Is this anyhow possible, and which way should I go?

I've tried to sketch it here:

> [] option a
>
> [] option b
>
> [] option c
>
> [] "TEXTBOX HERE"

Answer (score 0):

Well it can get complicated but, here it is..

You can add `onClickListener` to that radiobutton and set its text like `"Enter the text"`.

Then, in in `onclick()` open a custom dialog box which accepts text. then set value received from there in your radio button text by `radioButt.setText(value entered);`.

[Custom Dialog example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/). in here just add editText in place of image view and text view.